# Significato dell'espressione "di fortuna" in questo passaggio

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Stavi scomodo nel letto, come i soldati nei «castelli» **di fortuna**. Il letto era corto per le tue gambe, ti costringeva a tenere le ginocchia piegate. Il materasso era di crine, vecchio, tutto asperità, pareva vi fossero nascoste delle pietre. Siccome i tedeschi avevano saccheggiato la biancheria, l’ospedale forniva soltanto una coperta, leggera, bucata in più punti.

Il significato di "castelli" in questo brano  suppongo sia quello spiegato nel punto 4 e della voce ["castello" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/castello), cioè

> Impalcatura verticale di legno a più piani sui quali, in caserme, rifugi, dormitorî pubblici, baraccamenti provvisorî, ecc., sono appoggiate reti, tele, pancacci per dormire; impalcature analoghe, con due (raram. più) letti sovrapposti, sono talora usate anche in abitazioni private, soprattutto per farvi dormire bambini o ragazzi (*letti a castello*).

Per quanto riguarda l'espressione "di fortuna", anche sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fortuna/) ho trovato

> la locuz. agg. *di fortuna* è passata a indicare qualsiasi cosa improvvisata alla meglio, o che costituisca un ripiego in caso di necessità: *abbiamo riparato il guasto con arnesi di f.; fecero la strada parte a piedi parte con mezzi di fortuna*.

Tuttavia non sono sicura che questo sia il senso nel brano sopra citato: i letti a castello si possono improvvisare alla meglio? Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei  dubbi?

Comment: A leggere il solo brano postato credo indichi _"baraccamenti provvisorî,"_  ed improvvisati alla meglio, ancor piu' con riferimento alla guerra. Il soldato per difendersi dai colpi nemici si barrica dietro qualcosa, e lo fortifica alla meno peggio --> di certo non ha il tempo di  renderlo anche comodo... Non credo si riferisca a letti a castello, ma semplicemente alla scomodita'. (Sopporta gli apostrofi per gli accenti che non ho su questo computer).

Answer (score 2):

Dal contesto direi che il paragone vuole esaltare il fatto che i letti fossero molto umili e inferiori alle normali aspettative di comodità.

Nello specifico, è verosimile (ma non scontato, vedi il commento di Hastur) che Pratolini si riferisse ai letti a castello su cui alloggiavano i soldati in tempo di guerra, cioè costruiti col massimo risparmio di risorse ed energie. In breve: letti a castello arrangiàti.